# Publish MQTT message via javascript

Tags: javascript, mqtt, paho

I'm trying to publish a MQTT message via javascript using the Paho MQTT js client:

```
gClient = new Paho.Client("192.168.178.34", 9001, "clientId");
gClient.send("mytopic", "myvalue", 1, true);
```

As I can see in another MQTT client, the message is actually sent. But strangely the QOS is 0 (not 1) and the message is NOT retained.

According to the documentation https://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/jsdoc/Paho.MQTT.Client.html it *should* work. Why doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly the QOS is only between the a client and the broker, not between the 2 clients, so even if the message is published at QOS 1, if the client has subscribed at QOS 0 that is what the the client will see.

Secondly I'm 99% sure you will only see the retained bit set in the other client when the message is delivered as part of the response to a new subscription, e.g. if you publish the message with the retained bit set, then subscribe a new client to that topic. If a client is already connected then they won't see the retained bit set as it's just a normal delivery at that point.

Comment: Thanks for that info, good to know. But I still think that there's something wrong. E.g. newly connecting clients receive old values. This leads me to believe that the retained flag on my new messages was actually not set.

Comment: What do you mean by old value? A new client will always receive the last message published with the retained bit set